# How to nest elements with different tags in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt

I am rather new when it comes to doing xslt transforms. I am trying to convert the following xml code (using xslt 1.0):

```
<generic_etd>
  <dc.contributor>NSERC</dc.contributor>
  <dc.creator>gradstudent</dc.creator>
  <dc.date>2013-05-07</dc.date>
  <dc.format>30 pages</dc.format>
  <dc.format>545709 bytes</dc.format>
  <thesis.degree.name>Theses (M.Eng.)</thesis.degree.name>
  <thesis.degree.level>masters</thesis.degree.level>
  <thesis.degree.discipline>Dept. of Mechanical Engineering<thesis.degree.discipline>
  <thesis.degree.grantor>Concordia University</thesis.degree.grantor> 
</generic_etd>
```

into the following format:

```
 <etd_ms:thesis> 
   <etd_ms:contributor>NSERC</etd_ms:contributor>
   <etd_ms:creator>gradstudent</etd_ms:creator>
   <etd_ms:date>2013-05-07</etd_ms:date>
   <etd_ms:format>30 pages</etd_ms:format>
   <etd_ms:format>545709 bytes</etd_ms:format>
   <etd_ms:degree>
      <etd_ms:name>Theses (M.Eng.)</etd_ms:name>
      <etd_ms:level>masters</etd_ms:level>
      <etd_ms:discipline>Dept. of Mechanical Engineering</etd_ms:discipline>
      <etd_ms:grantor>Concordia University</etd_ms:grantor>
   </etd_ms:degree>
</etd_ms:thesis>
```

The problem I am having is two fold. I can create everything except the degree portion of xml just fine. However when I try to add the degree portion with the appropriate nesting it is not working for me. I have looked on line for some clues but the xsl:key call doesn't seem to be the correct thing to use. Any ideas how to accomplish this? I suspect it must be relatively straight forward if you know what you are doing (unlike me).

Thanks.

Comment: Show your XSL stylesheet please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generated XSLT on version 1.0 is able to get your desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:etd_ms="dsfdsfsdf">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name()='generic_etd'">
        <etd_ms:thesis>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </etd_ms:thesis>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains(name(),'thesis.degree.')"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="{concat('etd_ms:',substring-after(name(),'.'))}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="new" match="*[contains(name(),'thesis.degree.')][1]">
    <etd_ms:degree>
      <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(name(),'thesis.degree.')]">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('etd_ms:',substring-after(name(),'thesis.degree.'))}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </etd_ms:degree>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank-you, that worked perfectly! I am going through the code to make sure I understand it correctly and to see what I should have done.